# Using variables from a config/properties file in a perl script

Tags: perl, configuration-files, cpan

If I have a page of configurable variables separate from my perl script, how can I use them in it?

Say I have these variables in the file..

```
database.properties:

    database = "dbi:Oracle:host=host-321;sid=XE;port=1337","User","Passwd"

    table1 = CHANNEL

    table2 = NODE
```

...and I need them for these parts of my perl script:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($database);

open ROW,">","./report/archive/rprt-$now/row_counts.txt" or die "Unable to create file: $!";
    my $chanRows = $dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table1");
    my $nodeElemsRows = $dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table2 WHERE NODE_TYPE > 1");
    my $nodeDeviceRows = $dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table2 WHERE NODE_TYPE = 1");
    print ROW "Channels: $chanRows\n";
    print ROW "Network Elements: $nodeElemsRows\n";
    print ROW "Devices: $nodeDeviceRows";
close ROW;
```

Obviously just simply putting $database, $table1 and $table2 in there like that won't do any good, so what is the right way to go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked [Config::File](http://search.cpan.org/~gwolf/Config-File-1.50/lib/Config/File.pm)?

Comment: Note also that unless you are _really_ certain that they text in those files is safe, interpolating into your SQL query string leave you vulnerable. [Learn from Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Config%3a%3aTiny).  Your configuration file could look like:

```
[databaseproperties]

    database = "dbi:Oracle:host=host-321;sid=XE;port=1337","User","Passwd"

    table1 = CHANNEL

    table2 = NODE
```

And your script something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::Tiny;
my $config = Config::Tiny->new;
$config = Config::Tiny->read('myconfig');
my $database = $config->{databaseproperties}->{database};
print "DATABASE = $database\n";
my $table1 = $config->{databaseproperties}->{table1};
print "TABLE-1  = $table1\n";
my $table2 = $config->{databaseproperties}->{table2};
print "TABLE-2  = $table2\n";
```